# HTML Multiple carriage returns

Tags: html

I am attempting to make a title page with a good amount of whitespace in between aspects on the page (title, author, annotated by, foreword by, translated by, etc.). I am struggling to figure out the HTML coding that would yield multiple carriage returns (with no text along the way). As e.g., I would like something like this (all centered on the page):

**Title**

Author



Foreword by...


Any ideas? While using the br tag (successfully) here to describe my issue, when I put multiple br tags into my editor and then run the updater, the 'excess' br tags disappear.

Comment: What is this "updater" you refer to?

Comment: Sounds like you need a new editor.  You already have code which accomplishes the task (though using styling instead of markup for this *would* be preferable), but you're using tools which modify your code for you for some reason.  You can try with something as simple as Notepad, it won't modify your code for you.

Comment: Sorry for the poor lingo. I'm using an online program, Pressbooks, for my purposes. My 'updater' is simply the 'compiler,' what I use to implement the changes I make to the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy as:

```
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
...
```

Neither editor or browser should remove them...
You can also try:

```
<div style="height:100px;"></div>
```

if you want a fixed size "spacer".

Comment: Thanks, AdamCalvetBohl! Indeed, the editor removes those multiple tags, and I've inquired with them why. In the meantime, your alternate suggestion is a great one. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe it's not a very elegant way to do it, but it'll do the trick...