# How to use <br> multiple times in HTML

Tags: html

This is my code:

```html
<HTML>
Hello
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
Good bye!
</HTML>
```

Is there an easier way instead of using 10 
 tags?

Comment: Sure, margins and/or padding and/or positioning

Comment: Why would one want to do this? CSS ist responsible for design and layout, not HTML.

Comment: Generally, this is considered poor form for HTML. You should place all your information (tags and content) in the HTML, but all styling (including whitespace) should be defined in CSS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Multiple carriage returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36770634/html-multiple-carriage-returns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this happen using `javascript`. Sort of like this:

```js
var breakItem = document.getElementById("break")

breakItem.innerHTML = "<br>".repeat(10)
```

```html
<HTML>
Hello
<div id="break"></div>
Good bye!
</HTML>
```

The `.repeat` function repeats the string `<br>` 10 times, then adds it to the `div`'s `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 5):

`<br>` is use for line break in html.

If you want to add multiple blank line you can use

```
<br style="line-height:N;">
```

where N is the number of blank line or you can write in px

e.g.

```
<br style = "line-height:100;">
```

or

```
<br style = "line-height:100px;">
```

first one give you 100 blank line and second one give you 100px space

Comment: Didn't work in jupyter notebook markdown cell.

Answer (score 4):

You can use CSS `margin-bottom` property

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin

```css
.br {margin-bottom: 10em}
```

```html
<HTML>
Hello
<p class="br"></p>
Good bye!
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are after, if you are after just the space from multiple `<br>` then you can use css positioning elements insteads (padding, top, margin, etc.)
Or, if you specifically want x amount of `<br>` elements, you can use an inline JavaScript for loop:

```
<HTML>
    Hello
    <script>
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
            document.write("<br>");
        }
    </script>
    Good bye!

</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround way of adding adjustable vertical space:
(works in **Jupyter Notebook markdown** cells)

```
<hr style="border:none; margin-bottom:2.2em">
```

Change the em number to adjust.